# Problem installing sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv extension for php@7.0

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, sqlsrv

Im installing SQL Server on my macbook. Right now i want to use mssql as my database for my laravel project.

Here is some info:

- Laravel 5.5
- PHP7.0
- SQL Server run on docker
- MacOS Big Sur

Right now, im try to install sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv extension to my php by using

`sudo pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv`

but apparently this extension required php 7.3.0 and above.

How can i select specific version of php extension using pecl install command? Im stucked for a few days for this problem

Answer (score 0):

5.3.0 is the latest version with support for 7.0

```
sudo pecl install sqlsrv-5.3.0 pdo_sqlsrv-5.3.0
```